# Com ler numeros sem pressionar "enter" em linguagem C?

Tags: c

estou escrevendo um programa, e estou com um pequeno problema.
Ao escolher uma das opções deve se apertar o "enter" pra prosseguir, porem ao apertar "enter" ele já entra na tela seguinte, pulando assim a primeira função de printf onde eu deveria escrever o nome do login, indo assim direto pra senha...
Segue o exemplo do codigo:

```
int numero;
printf("\n\t\t MENU PRINCIPAL\n\n1- Estoque\n2- Loja\n3- Sair\n\nEscolha a opcao desejada: ");
scanf("%d", &numero);
fflush(stdin); // Limpar o buffer do teclado
switch (numero) {
case 1:
    system("cls");
    //Estoque();
    break;
case 2:
    system("cls");
    Loja();
    break;
case 3:
    system("cls");
    system("EXIT");
    return 0;
default:
    printf("Opcao invalida\n\n");
}
```

}

Loja() {
char c;
char cadastro_login[30];
char cadastro_senha[30];
char login[30];
char senha[30];
int a = 0, b = 1, d = 3;

```
printf("\n\t\t CADASTRO\n\n");
fflush(stdin); 
printf("Crie um login: ");
fflush(stdin); 
gets(cadastro_login);
printf("\nCrie uma senha: ");
do {
    c = _getch();
    if (isprint(c)) {
        cadastro_senha[a] = c; 
        a++;
        printf("*");
    }
    else if (c == 8 && a) { 
        cadastro_senha[a] = '\0';
        a--;
        printf("\b\b");
    }
} while (c != 13); 
cadastro_senha[a] = '\0';
printf("\n\n\t\t Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!\n\n");
system("cls");
do {
    printf("\nLogin: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(login);
    printf("\nSenha: ");
    a = 0;
    do {
        c = _getch();
        if (isprint(c)) {
            senha[a] = c;
            a++;
            printf("*");
        }
        else if (c == 8 && a) {
            senha[a] = '\0';
            a--;
            printf("\b\b");
        }
    } while (c != 13);
    senha[a] = '\0';

    if (!strcmp(cadastro_login, login) && !strcmp(cadastro_senha, senha)) {
        printf("\n\n\t\t LOGIN EFETUADO COM SUCESSO!\n\n");
        b = 0;
    }
    else {
        system("cls");
        d--; 
        if (d)printf("\n\n\t\a\t SENHA INVALIDA - TENTE NOVAMENTE... \n\n");
    }
} while (b && d); 
if (!d)printf("\a\n\n\t\tCONTA BLOQUEADA - VOCE ERROU 3 VEZES CONSECUTIVAS.\n\n"); 
system("pause");
system("cls");
```

}

Comment: @RafhainiVeronezi WOW!!! vlw mesmo!! Muito obrigado, funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar um getChar(), Logo após o scanf.

```
printf("\n\t\t MENU PRINCIPAL\n\n1- Estoque\n2- Loja\n3- Sair\n\nEscolha a opcao desejada: ");
scanf("%d", &numero);
**getchar();**
```